# Get Manager Email and add to the TO

Tags: vba, email, outlook

How do I get the manager email (the person the employee is reporting to "outlook properties>organization") to automatically add it in the code?

The code works if I hardcode the manager email but I want to apply this to different departments where managers are different.

```
' Sending a copy of the email to the supervisor
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
oMail.Body = "Please review the below email sent by an employee from your division" _
& vbCrLf & _
"**********************************************************" _
& vbCrLf & _
Item.Body
oMail.Subject = Item.Subject & " (Email Revision)"
oMail.To = **((MANAGER'S EMAIL))**
oMail.Send
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Application.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().Manager.

Be prepared to handle GetExchangeUser and Manager returning null.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, I tried it but it gave me a 438 Run time error stating that the object does not support this property or method.

Comment: Thank you again! I tried the following and it worked! oMail.To = Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Manager

Comment: You really need to break that line into "Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry", call GetExchangeUser(), make sure it is not Nothing, retrieve the Manager property, check again that it is not Nothing, then read the Address property.